Decoupled communication between Stateful and a plain object
Looking for an answer from a senior architect in Flutter who knows the in and out of the SDK and the platform.
Objective is to get notified once a Stateful object comes to life or gets instantiated. The listener in this case is an isolated object.
At the moment I have solved using an EventBus class, and the reason why I'm not satisfied is because I'm looking for something built-in or provided by the framework or the environment. (zero dependency, no 3rd party package either).
For example, in HTML and ReactJS we have window.addEventListener, and dispatchEvent. In Go language we have channels. In iOS we have built-in Notification Center (observer model)
I did try StreamController but nay. Use case of it is different, it's more of sending stream of data with error and close handlers. Not really a compatible use case.
Edit Lateral Thinking? maybe it's not recommended but can we use keys to get hold of the instances, I can't instantiate stateful widgets using the keys because they are instantiated automatically as user navigates the app.
Just think out loud here. Are they keys stored somewhere.

Foo
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {

  const Foo({super.key});

  @override
  State<FooState> createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    EventBus().dispatch("MOUNTED", this);
  }

}


Bar
class Bar extends StatefulWidget {

  const Bar({super.key});

  @override
  State<BarState> createState() => _BarState();
}

class _BarState extends State<Bar> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    EventBus().dispatch("MOUNTED", this);
  }

}


EventBus Objective is to get rid of this EventBus and use something provided by the Framework
class EventBus {
  static final EventBus _instance = EventBus._internal();

  factory EventBus() {
    return _instance;
  }

  EventBus._internal();

  final Map<String, List<void Function(dynamic sender)>> _listeners = {};

  void subscribe(String event, void Function(dynamic sender) callback) {
    if (_listeners[event] == null) {
      _listeners[event] = [];
    }
    _listeners[event]!.add(callback);
  }

  void unsubscribe(String event, void Function(dynamic sender) callback) {
    _listeners[event]?.remove(callback);
  }

  void dispatch(String event, dynamic sender) {
    if (_listeners[event] != null) {
      for (var callback in _listeners[event]!) {
        callback(sender);
      }
    }
  }
}


Isolated plain object - objective is to get to know once the widgets comes to life.
class Isolated {

  void startup() {
    EventBus().subscribe("MOUNTED", OnMount);
    // lateral thinking, maybe get hold of Keys from the framework
  }

  void OnMount(dynamic sender) { // if either of foo and bar are instantiated.
    // we can check sender here if it's `Foo` or `Bar`
  }

}


One way could be using InheritedWidget

Ensure that your Isolated object is a singleton. This is not absolutely required but otherwise it will require more care when working with instances.

class Isolated {
  static final Isolated _instance = Isolated._();

  factory Isolated() => _instance;

  Isolated._();

  void onInit(dynamic sender) {
    // implement
  }
}


Create an InheritedWidget used to provide the Isolated instance in a widget tree:

class IsolatedProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  final Isolated isolated;

  const IsolatedProvider({
    super.key,
    required this.isolated,
    required super.child,
  });

  @override
  bool updateshouldNotify(IsolatedProvider oldWidget) => false;
}


Use the inherited widget above to provide the Isolated instance to your widget tree. This can be done anywhere as long as it is above where you plan to use instances of Foo and Bar. For example, we wrap the entire App widget:

runApp(
  IsolatedProvider(
    // Factory constructor returns the singleton.
    isolated: Isolated(),
    // Usually a MaterialApp
    child: const App(),
  ),
);


Add a shortcut in Isolated to easily retrieve the instance from the widget tree:

class Isolated {
  // ...


  // ... or maybeOf(...) if it should be nullable
  static Isolated of(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<IsolatedProvider>()!;
    return provider.isolated;
  }
}


In your widgets you can use the Isolated instance:

class Foo extends StatefulWidget {

  const Foo({super.key});

  @override
  State<FooState> createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  late final isolated = Isolated.of(context);
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Usability of a FooState is questionable here. Maybe it should be a public class or implement a well known interface.
    isolated.onInit(this);
  }

}

Technically, you can drop all the InheritedWidget stuff and use Isolated similarly to how EventBus was used.
However, this mechanism is more flexible and has some long term advantages over a pure singleton:

if needed, it will allow you to provide different instances to different parts of your widget tree
it allows you to easily provide a mock Isolated for tests

